# Character encoding in html5 for UCS - 2 or RDS

Tags: html, character-encoding, opera

[image]I have been trying to use character encoding in html5 as below :

```
    <meta charset="UCS-2" />    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UCS-2" />
```

and

```
    <meta charset="Utf-8" />  
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Utf-8" />
```

and

```
    <meta charset="Utf-16" />  
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Utf-16" />
```

But, none of these helped me to resolve the following error in Opera console :

Syntax error at line xxx while loading: unexpected character: U+0007.

Please let me know if anyone has any solution.

Thanks
Sneha

Comment: At the very least, set the encoding in the HTTP header. Declaring it in the document itself means the browser has to first read the document in an unknown encoding to figure out its encoding. Since UCS-2 is not ASCII compatible, that's bound to cause problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character U+0007 is disallowed according to all HTML specifications. This does not depend on the character encoding. The HTML5 drafts seem to be silent about the set of allowed characters, but this presumably implies no change and, besides, if you have a problem on a browser, then what matters is what browsers do, not what some draft says.

I you think that your document does not actually contain U+0007, you need to disclose the relevant part of your document – preferably, a minimal self-contained document that demonstrates the problem.

The document’s character encoding should be declared to match the actual encoding, not by trial and error. “UCS-2” is not a [registered](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets) name (“ISO-10646-UCS-2” is, but you probably won’t find a browser that recognizes it). There is normally no good reason to use UTF-16, partly due to insufficient browser support. An UTF-16 encoded document is best recoded into UTF-8 for use on the web.

Comment: It's implicitly disallowed in HTML5 as it'll throw a parse error in the tokenizer.

Comment: Is there any chances in near future that browsers support it?